# How to check glusterfs-server status outside the machine?

Tags: glusterfs

I want to check glusterfs-server status, but not in the machine running the server. For example, I want to use `curl gluster-server-ip:24007` from the client-side and then check if 200 OK is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heketi may help.

It is RESTful based volume management framework for GlusterFS

link:
https://github.com/heketi/heketi

Comment: Will heketi check servers' status periodically? Or only save status when creating volumes?

Comment: @Pao It can check status dynamically is my understanding.